# What is an endpoint for custom post type comments in REST API?

Tags: rest-api

In my react project i am using worpdress as backend and need to use my custom post type `events` comments also.

So as per the WordPress documentation for comments API i am using an endpoint like this
“`/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?events=704`”; so according to this it should display only 704 post-ids comments.

But in my case it returns me all the comments which are posted in the `post_type = post` also. See below JSON result of the above API endpoint for custom post type.

[image]

Here is a `'post_type' => post` comment's data that returns a correct result.

[image]

I have passed this argument in the register_post_type    'show_in_rest'=> true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post types are still posts, so to retrieve comments for a specific post of a custom post type you use the `post` argument. From the [API reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#list-comments):

> `post`    Limit result set to comments assigned to specific post IDs.

So:

```
json/wp/v2/comments?post=704
```

Comment: Okay, so by doing this i am getting this error message: https://prnt.sc/onbfvm

Comment: Seems self explanatory to me. You don't have read permissions for comments for that post. That can happen if the post (or 'event') isn't published, you don't have its read capability or the post type isn't in REST.